# There are "AlterTable" command in dbx metadata?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

How do I use the dbx metadata to modify an existing database? I'm trying, but I just able to create a new tables, with the new columns, new definitions... For example, can I add a new column into an existing database?

The "CreateTable" command dont makes changes... i'm right? There are "AlterTable" command or something like this?

I'm using Delphi XE with Firebird

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use SQL commands directly, then you can do anything that your database supports. No need to have DBX interfering with that process.

Comment: I dont think that is the way. Whatever then, please tell me how do you working on day by day.